# Start current instance of service in an activity

Tags: java, android, service

I have a service like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    .
    .
    .
    private Activity source;
    public setActivity(Activity source){
        this.source=source;
    }
}
```

and an activity like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        .
        .
        MyService service=new MyService();
        service.setActivity(this);
        //in this place I want start my service.
        //but if I use Intent, it run another instance of my service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

How do I start current instance service? in this place I want start `service`.

Comment: "but if I use Intent, it run another instance of my service." - No it doesn't. `Service`s are singletons.

Comment: when my service starts and i check name field, it is null.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed the first part of your `onCreate()` method. That's because you can't instantiate a `Service` with `new` and have it work as you're expecting. The `MyService` instance you created above the `startService()` call isn't actually running. If you want to pass a `String` to your `Service`, attach it as an extra on the `Intent` you're using to start it.

Comment: OK, how do I run a method in service class before start it?

Comment: I had edited my comment above. You may need to refresh the page.

Comment: In my real program I want pass the Activity itself to service.

Comment: refer to `Intent` documentation to see what can be passed in its "extras"

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to keep an instance of activity inside a service.

Android guides say :

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

You can start a service in background with intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

If you attempt a response from this service, checkout [tutorials related to service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for a better understanding of it.